# Translation Help 2

Tags: grammar, translation, korean-to-english

I’m translating a romance comic and there’s a scene that shows an interaction between two characters, let’s call them character A and character B. Character A says to character B the following (B is 기자):

근데 기자님 정말 못한다. 귀엽긴 한데, 다음엔 연습 좀 해와요. 다음이 있을진 모르겠지만.
 
And character B thinks:

…웃기는 소리 하고 있네.

Even though I got some translation help, I still don’t understand what character A’s implying. I gathered this:

근데 기자님 정말 못한다 - 'By the way, you're really bad at this'

귀엽긴 한데, 다음엔 연습 좀 해와요 - ‘It's cute, but please do some practice for next time'.

다음이 있을진 모르겠지만 - ‘I don’t know if we meet again, though’.

…웃기는 소리 하고 있네 - ‘What nonsense/bullshit’.

But I don’t see a logical chain here. First character A says 귀엽긴 한데, 다음엔 연습 좀 해와요, but then they counter it with 다음이 있을진 모르겠지만. They ask B to practice, but they state that this day may never come.

Is 다음이 있을진 모르겠지만 some kind of open-ended statement, to leave B to decide if they want to meet (or not)? Or are they implying that B’s so bad that they don't want to see them ever again? Hahaha... The pictures in the comic don’t help either because they’re just as ambiguous.

So I’d appreciate if someone explained all of this to me.

Comment: A and B seem somewhat friendly to each other, as otherwise they wouldn’t have talked to each other. A is teasing or being mean to B. And then "웃기는 소리하고 있네" shows that B understood what A has said to B.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm... I think the situation is pretty unambiguous?  Person A is very condescending, which is making B angry - with a bit of paraphrasing, the dialogue is like:

> A: Oh you are *so* bad!  You're cute though, I'll give you that.  Please practice more before next time, though I doubt there will be a next time!

> B: What a load of bullshit.  (Or, maybe, "What an asshole.")

Comment: thanks! Now i see how it is. Your translation's great, really funny, hahaha :D